# Strage 5px margin

Tags: css

I created a react app, and all I have in my App.css is this

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
```

nothing more, is a fresh new app created and for some reason it automatically adds 5px, because if I say something like margin-left: -5px; it behaves as it should when you type margin:0.
Do someone met this before?

Comment: try {box-sizing:border-box;}

Comment: I tried, nothing, I tried display:block too

Comment: you could try important on both

Comment: there might be a defualt in a browser, and wildcard could be weak, idk, worth a try